# RabbitMQ: Publish more than one item?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I wrote a quick wrapper around RabbitMQ, but struggling to publish more than 1 message?

If I have a batch of 1,000 messages that need to be added at a random time, I use PublishBatch which just looops BasicPublish.

For some reason, I'm ending up with sometimes half, sometimes 90% of the items I added?

What is going on here? If I add 100 items, I'm ending up with 21? Then 35? Then 13?

TEST:

```
var messages = new List<string>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    messages.Add(RandomString(200));
}

Console.WriteLine($"Sending {messages.Count} messages to the queue...");
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
services.GetRequiredService<MessageQueueWrapper>().PublishBatch("some-test-queue", messages);
```

RabbitMQ Client Wrapper:

```
public class MessageQueueWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;

    public MessageQueueWrapper(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
    }

    public void QueueDeclare(string queueName, bool durable = true)
    {
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: durable, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
    }

    public void BasicPublish(string queueName, string message, string exchange = "")
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        _channel.BasicPublish(exchange, queueName, null, bytes);
    }

    public void PublishBatch(string queueName, List<string> messages, string exchange = "")
    {
        QueueDeclare(queueName);

        foreach (var bytes in messages.Select(message => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)))
        {
            _channel.BasicPublish(exchange, queueName, null, bytes);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
        _channel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is your application exits before all of the messages have left the local TCP buffer, or something like that. You should read about publisher confirmations.

Comment: The `BasicPublish` is async. as @LukeBakken said, you are closing the client before the end send.  You can use the publish confirm to check when all the messages are confirmed or just wait a bit before closing